# ASP.Net MVC - Razor Displaying account totals for customers by Month/Year Columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have a statement summary view that i need to show total balance on a customers account by month and year.

I have created the linq query and view models which successfully pull this data from the database.

I want to display this data in a tabular form e.g.

**View Desired**

[image]

My LINQ code

```
var monthlyTotals = from t in db.InvoiceItems.AsEnumerable()
                                 // where t.Invoice.LegalFile.IsClosed == false
                                  group t by t.Invoice.LegalFile.Client into g
                                  select new StatementSummaryVM
                                  {
                                      Client = g.Key,
                                      GrandTotal = g.Sum(x => x.AmountInclVAT),
                                      MonthlyTotals = from i in g
                                              group i by new
                                                    {
                                                        month = i.ItemDate.Month,
                                                        year = i.ItemDate.Year
                                                    }
                                              into d
                                              select new MonthlyTotalsVM
                                              {
                                                  Date = new DateTime(d.Key.year, d.Key.month,1),
                                                  Amount = d.Sum(s => s.AmountInclVAT)
                                              }
                                  };

            return monthlyTotals;

        }
```

My View Model

```
public class StatementSummaryVM
{
    [Display(Name = "File No.")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MonthlyTotalsVM> MonthlyTotals { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Grand Total")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public decimal GrandTotal { get; set; }
}

public class MonthlyTotalsVM
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

My Current View Code

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>File No.</th>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Grand Total</th>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <th></th>
            foreach (var monthlyTotal in item.MonthlyTotals)
            {
                <th>@Html.DisplayFor(model => monthlyTotal.Date)</th>
            }
        }
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Client.Id</td>
             <td>@item.Client.Name </td>
             <td>@item.GrandTotal</td>

        @foreach (var monthlyTotal in item.MonthlyTotals)
        {
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => monthlyTotal.Date)</td>
            <td>@monthlyTotal.Amount</td>
        }
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Which looks like this when rendered

**Current Rendered View**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4oj2.png):[image]

Im struggling to get this to display correctly.

Any help would really be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: The first thing you need to do is remove `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => monthlyTotal.Date)</td>` in the 2nd `foreach` block

Comment: Hi Stephen. Absolutely. I only left it there to help me see what the date is of the monthlyTotal model so i can try figure out how to structure the view

Comment: So what is it you trying to do? You have shown 2 images that have no relationship to each other at all. If the last image is the 'real' data, then what should your table look like?

Comment: what i need is at the top of the post. Under "VIEW DESIRED "there is a an excel snippet of what the report should look like: i.e. display monthly totals in appropriate date column.

Comment: If you show an actual image of what the real data should look like then we can help. At the moment it makes no sense. The data in the first image has no relationship to the data in the 2nd image!

Comment: sorrry about that Stephen. I have updated the post above to show my desired view with the actual data

Comment: Can you update the bottom image after you remove the `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => monthlyTotal.Date)</td>` so its easier to compare (the issue is that your `MonthlyTotals` property needs to be initialized with all months in the range that your displaying and then you update the corresponding month based on your grouping

Comment: i've updated the bottom image. What you said makes sense but could you help on how exactly to do that Stephen. It took me forever to figure out that linq query.

Comment: Do you really want non-consecutive months (i.e. you have missed out Mar and Apr)? That makes it a little harder. And do you have a range of dates that you want to display - e.g. `.Where(x => x.ItemDate > someDate && x.ItemDate < anotherDate)`?

Comment: in real life there wouldnt be non-consecutive months. My data sample is just small. so No. Yes, i would be applying a data range.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code is only returning a collection of `MonthlyTotalsVM` where a value actually exists and the key to making this work is to initialize the collection with a `MonthlyTotalsVM` for each month in the range of dates you want to display and then update the corresponding item in the collection based on the index of the month.

Assuming your method accepts parameters for the startDate and the number of months to display in the table, you code would be

```cs
public ActionResult StatementSummary(DateTime startDate, int months)
{
    // Get the start and end dates
    startDate = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1); // ensure first day of month
    DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(months + 1);
    // Initialize the model
    List<StatementSummaryVM> model = new List<StatementSummaryVM>();
    // Filter the data and group by client
    var data = db.InvoiceItems
        .Where(i => i.ItemDate >= startDate && i.ItemDate < endDate)
        .GroupBy(i => i.Invoice.LegalFile.Client);
    // Create a StatementSummaryVM for each client group
    foreach(var clientGroup in data)
    {
        StatementSummaryVM summary = new StatementSummaryVM(startDate, months)
        {
            Client = clientGroup.Key,
            GrandTotal = clientGroup.Sum(x => x.AmountInclVAT)
        };
        // Group by month/year
        foreach(var monthGroup in clientGroup.GroupBy(x => new { Month = x.Date.Month, Year = x.Date.Year }))
        {
            // Get the index of the month
            int index = ((monthGroup.Key.Year - startDate.Year) * 12) + monthGroup.Key.Month - startDate.Month;
            summary.MonthlyTotals[index].Amount = monthGroup.First().AmountInclVAT; // or .Sum(m => m.AmountInclVAT) if there are multiple invoives per month
        }
        model.Add(summary);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And then change your `StatementSummaryVM` model to add a constructor that initializes the collection

```cs
public class StatementSummaryVM
{
    public StatementSummaryVM(DateTime startDate, int months)
    {
        MonthlyTotals = new List<MonthlyTotalsVM>();
        for (int i = 0; i < months; i++)
        {
            MonthlyTotals.Add(new MonthlyTotalsVM() { Date = startDate.AddMonths(i) });
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen. I made a few changes as i have a list of invoice items to be totalled in the invoice but otherwise your solution was spot on! I dont know how you do it but you are something else. Thank you !